# SSMS Copying error in Import Export Wizard and More

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, import-from-excel, sql-server-2019

Whenever I try to import an Excel file into my database half the time it would be successful but the imported table doesn't appear even after a refresh or an error occurs in the import export wizard during the copying phase.

This is the report from the wizard:

```
Operation stopped...

- Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)    
- Initializing Connections (Success)    
- Setting SQL Command (Success)    
- Setting Source Connection (Success)    
- Setting Destination Connection (Success)    
- Validating (Success)    
- Prepare for Execute (Success)    
- Pre-execute (Success)    
- Executing (Success)    
- Copying to `Sheet1$` (Error)
    Messages
    * Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
    An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Spreadsheet is full.".
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
    
    * Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Sheet1$.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Sheet1$.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
    
    * Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Sheet1$" (26) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (37). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
    
    * Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
    
    * Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Sheet1$ returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)      

- Post-execute (Success)
    Messages
    * Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Sheet1$" wrote 0 rows.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssis-error-code-dts_e_primeoutputfailed)

Comment: "Error code: 0x80004005" can also mean "Access Denied." Is it possible you have the Excel spreadsheet open in Excel - or any other program - while trying to import it via SSMS?